# Replace entire sheet with another in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'd like to do is warehouse information from a particular sheet within a spreadsheet and copy it to a second spreadsheet at the end of every day.  The second spreadsheet will run complex pivots and reports against the copied information that don't need to run throughout the day.

I can set up a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) which will run the job every day within an hour block.

I'm working on the following script which uses [`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet()) to get the current Spreadsheet. Then gets the individual sheet to backup with [`spreadsheet.getSheetByName`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)).  And then uses the [`sheet.copyTo`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) method to add the current sheet to a new spreadsheet.  I'm getting the new spreadsheet by looking up the id with [`SpreadsheetApp.openById`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)) all like this:

```js
function startBackupJob() {

  var currentSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var masterSheet = currentSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  var backupSpreadSheetId = "#######################################";
  var backupSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(backupSpreadSheetId);

  // var backupSheet = backupSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  // backupSpreadSheet.deleteSheet(backupSheet);

  masterSheet.copyTo(backupSpreadSheet).setName("Sheet1");

}
```

The issue I'm having is that `copyTo` will create a new worksheet rather than overwrite the existing spreadsheet.  The point of moving to the new workbook is to run pivot tables off the data and not re-wire them to point to a new sheet.

I can delete the previous sheet to make room for the new one, but this kills the references on the PivotTable as well, so it doesn't help much.

**Is there an easy way to transfer the entire contents of one worksheet to another?**

---

This is similar to (but different from) the following questions:

- [How do I script making a backup copy of a spreadsheet to an archive folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11839952/1366033) - However, I don't want to move the whole file, but a specific sheet within the spreadsheet.
- [How can copy specifics sheet to another spreadsheet using google script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17099497/1366033) & [copy one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet with formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19791132/1366033) - However copying produces a new sheet, whereas I need to replace the contents of an existing sheet
- [Scripts, copy cell from one sheet to another sheet EVERYDAY at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24500761/1366033) - However, I do want to replace the entire sheet, rather than just specific cells within the sheet.

---

**Update**

I might be able to do this by calling [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) on each sheet and then using [`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) and [`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) like this:

```js
var currentValues = masterSheet.getRange(1, 1, 50, 50).getValues()
backupSheet.getRange(1, 1, 50, 50).setValues(currentValues)
```

But I'm worried about edge cases where the master sheet has a different available range than the backup sheet.  I also don't want to hardcode in the range, but for it to encompass the entire sheet.  If I call `.getRange("A:E")` then the two worksheets have to have the exact same number of rows which is not likely.

Comment: Instead of copying the data into the second spreadsheet file, I'd have an intermediary data file, that the second spreadsheet file can access.  It seems like right now, your second sheet isn't dynamic enough to figure out how to reference the incoming data.  I'm just making a wild guess here.  It seems like part of the problem is the second sheet being able to set a reference to the new data.  You could set the values in the second sheet cell by cell if you needed to for whatever reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your update has you about 90% of the way there. The trick is to explicitly check the size of the destination sheet before you copy data into it. For example, if I did something like this:

```js
var cromulentDocument = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var masterSheet = cromulentDocument.getSheetByName('master');
var logSheet = cromulentDocument.getSheetByName('log');
var hugeData = masterSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var rowsInHugeData = hugeData.length;
var colsInHugeData = hugeData[0].length;

/* cross fingers */
logSheet.getRange(1, 1, rowsInHugeData, colsInHugeData).setValues(hugeData);
```

...then my success would totally depend upon whether `logSheet` was at least as big as `masterSheet`. That's obvious, but what's less so is that if `logSheet` is **bigger** then there will be some old junk left over around the edges. Ungood.

Let's try something else. As before, we'll grab the master data, but we'll also resize `logSheet`. If we don't care about `logSheet` being too big we could probably just `clear()` the data in it, but let's be tidy.

```js
var cromulentDocument = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var masterSheet = cromulentDocument.getSheetByName('master');
var logSheet = cromulentDocument.getSheetByName('log');
var hugeData = masterSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var rowsInHugeData = hugeData.length;
var colsInHugeData = hugeData[0].length;

/* no finger crossing necessary */
var rowsInLogSheet = logSheet.getMaxRows();
var colsInLogSheet = logSheet.getMaxColumns();

/* adjust logSheet length, but only if we need to... */
if (rowsInLogSheet < rowsInHugeData) {
  logSheet.insertRowsAfter(rowsInLogSheet, rowsInHugeData - rowsInLogSheet);
} else if (rowsInLogSheet > rowsInHugeData) {
  logSheet.deleteRows(rowsInHugeData, rowsInLogSheet - rowsInHugeData);
}

/* likewise, adjust width */
if (colsInLogSheet < colsInHugeData) {
  logSheet.insertColumnsAfter(colsInLogSheet, colsInHugeData - colsInLogSheet);
} else if (colsInLogSheet > colsInHugeData) {
  logSheet.deleteColumns(colsInHugeData, colsInLogSheet - colsInHugeData);
}

/* barring typos, insert data with confidence */
logSheet.getRange(1, 1, rowsInHugeData, colsInHugeData).setValues(hugeData);
```

What's going on here is pretty straightforward. We figure out how big the log needs to be, and then adjust the destination sheet's size to match that data.

Comment: **Perfect**!  Side question: does all this rigmarole offer any benefit to just using [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) on the backup sheet and passing in the ID of the master sheet.  I'm mostly trying to improve performance because there are tons of rows and my suspicion is running the pivot tables within the same document is exacerbating the issue.  Import Range updates live, so that's nice, but then I'm worried it's going to have to spend just as much energy pushing changes that way.

Comment: As your "master" data gets bigger, this approach has more and more benefit because the spreadsheet will not be constantly checking for updates. I've also seen problems with `IMPORTRANGE` where the target area just shows blank until you forcibly refresh the cell with the `IMPORTRANGE` in it. I also regularly get problems where formulas (or pivots) that use `IMPORTRANGE`d data just do not see the underlying data at all even when it shows up in the UI.